# Using a responsive grid system, keep two columns on the same row while allowing more columns for larger screens

Tags: html, css

Here a simple snippet written with [Chota](https://jenil.github.io/chota/):

```css
.card {
  margin: 30px;
}

.tag {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.field {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/chota@latest">
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<div class="row is-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-6-md col-4-lg">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="is-center">
        <h4>Controllo remoto stufa</h4>
      </header>
      <p class="is-center">La stufa è<span class="tag">SPENTA</span></p>
      <div class="is-center">
        <button class="button error">ON/OFF</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/thermometer.svg?size=24">Temperatura
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <span class="tag field">22 °C</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/water-outline.svg?size=24">Umidità
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <span class="tag field">50% RH</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/calendar-month.svg?size=24">Data<span class="tag field">25/12/2023</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/clock-outline.svg?size=24">Ora<span class="tag field">12:00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here how it appears in large screens:

[image]

and in smaller screens:

[image]

I want, even in smaller screens to keep on the same line the lables (i.e. "Temperatura") and their values. Since the width of the grid system is 12 and the docs says:

> All columns are 100% for device width < 600px

I thought that adding two columns with class `col-6` should lead to have a single row with two columns even for smaller devices.

Obviously I'm wrong. How should I change my grid?

As a bonus... I would like to allow on larger screens to have a couple of fields (in the example like date and time) while on middle/smaller screens it should fall back to have only one field for row.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New library, but it basically flex layout, so either you look up a class with property `flex-wrap: nowrap` of just create a new one like my demo below (`.mobile-no-wrap`) and add it to where you need it.

> As a bonus... I would like to allow on larger screens to have a couple of fields (in the example like date and time) while on middle/smaller screens it should fall back to have only one field for row.

Basically just another case of `flex-wrap: nowrap`, add it to the parent div to make the childs inside on the same line, then break it when in smaller screen size using media query and reverse the `flex-wrap` property from `nowrap` to `wrap`.

```css
.card {
  margin: 30px;
}

.tag {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.field {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.row.mobile-no-wrap {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/chota@latest">
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<div class="row is-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-6-md col-4-lg">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="is-center">
        <h4>Controllo remoto stufa</h4>
      </header>
      <p class="is-center">La stufa è<span class="tag">SPENTA</span></p>
      <div class="is-center">
        <button class="button error">ON/OFF</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row mobile-no-wrap">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/thermometer.svg?size=24">Temperatura
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <span class="tag field">22 °C</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mobile-no-wrap">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/water-outline.svg?size=24">Umidità
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <span class="tag field">50% RH</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/calendar-month.svg?size=24">Data<span class="tag field">25/12/2023</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 is-center">
          <img src="https://icongr.am/material/clock-outline.svg?size=24">Ora<span class="tag field">12:00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even with your snippet (using Firefox 120) when reducing the width of the screen below 600px it breaks the labels (i.e. "Temperatura") and the values. But there is still plenty of space for those elements.

Comment: @Mark Lol sorry, just some typo. check it again.

Comment: Yeah, now it works! Thanks. I'm going to play with the `nowrap` settings to learn how to use it!